# Deploy multiple asp.net mvc 4 projects of an solution in as an single application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm new to asp.Net MVC 4, therefore maybe a simple question for the most of you.

I want to deploy multiple projects of an solution as a single application and access to the different projects over an unique path:

```
Solution:
- project 1 --> helloworld.website (localhost:8082/website)   
- project 2 --> helloworld.webserviceapi (access over: localhost:8082/webservice)
```

I try to access the second application by creating a virtual directory, but it not working.

Comment: How have you created the virtual directories? You'll need to ensure that each one is created as an application rather than just a virtual directory within IIS itself. If you let Visual Studio create them automatically they probably won't be set up correctly

Comment: Hi Luiggi,

Thank you for your replay.

First I deployed my Website on IIS. After that, I selected the created site of my website and add the virtual directory over the IIS configuration. I entered a alias, in that case "webservice" and give the physical path of my web service project.

Then If I wanted to access to the webservice I got following error:

Error Summary HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid

Comment: Does this help? http://forums.asp.net/t/1115232.aspx

Comment: I Solved my problem:) After I created an virtual directory I turned it into an application (right click on created virtual directory --> Convert to Application). Many thanks for your help Luiggi.